# AngularJS - Check if component's bindings function is a function

Tags: angularjs, function, binding, components

I'm trying to check if my components bindings.
As you know, to bind a function you have to use the '&' char.

```
<pipeline-list-item
    item="item"
    is-selected="item === $ctrl.selectedItem"
    on-action="">
</pipeline-list-item>
```

---

```
.component('pipelineListItem', {
    restrict: 'E',
    bindings: {
        onAction: '&'
    },
    template: require('./pipeline-list-item.html'),

    controller($scope, RESULTS_TABS, SESSION_ACTIONS, SESSION_STATUSES, ACTIONS, Logger) {
        var that = this;

        that.actionClicked = function ($event, action) {
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $event.preventDefault();
            if (typeof that.onAction === 'function') {
                console.log(that.onAction);
                that.onAction({item: that.item, action});
            }
            else {
                Logger.error({
                    method_name: 'pipelineListItem.actionClicked.',
                    message: 'onAction function was not given to component.'
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

Because the '&' char AngularJS is wrapping the function with another function, what makes the typeof === 'function' return true.

[The function that I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1MrU.png)

Thanks, Itay.

Answer (score 4):

You have to append an '?' to your binding, so '&?' is the answer.

Now you can check it with "if(that.onAction) {that.onAction()}".

Have fun!

If you dont append the '?', you can still do that.onAction(). If a function is passed, it will call it. If nothing is passed, an empty function will be called.